# Firebase initialization returning "Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the following setup:

```
<button type="button" name="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="signIn()">
  <i class="fa fa-google"></i> &nbsp;Login With Google
</button>
<script src="js/firebase.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

firebase.js

```
// FIREBASE INITIALIZATION
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-app.js";
import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-analytics.js";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "fir-chat-application-3e442.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "fir-chat-application-3e442",
  storageBucket: "fir-chat-application-3e442.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "264006913204",
  appId: "XXXXXXXX",
  measurementId: "XXXXXXXX"
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

custom.js

```
function signIn(){
  var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
}
```

When I click on the `Login With Google` button I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
```

I checked everything again and again but I don't seem to catch the error. What mistake am I making here?

Comment: Please, obfuscate the sensible data in your `firebaseConfig`, don't show public.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing api v8 and v9.

```js
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-auth.js"

const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
```

Edit to demostrate that firebase scripts includes `GoogleAuthProvider`:

```html
<script type="module">

import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-auth.js"

console.info(GoogleAuthProvider)
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to the correct documentation of the version that I am using to follow?

Comment: Also, your code returns `Uncaught TypeError: Error resolving module specifier “firebase/auth”. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.` in the console

Comment: try someting like `import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.3.0/firebase-auth.js"`. I found the docs in: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?hl=en. The imports in that docs are from a node module, but can easy extrapolate to web modules.

Comment: Tried that.. Now returns `Uncaught ReferenceError: GoogleAuthProvider is not defined`